# combine special characters to previous index in array

Tags: javascript

Please help javascript masters. I have an array:

**["G", "A", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "E²", "…", ".", "~", "C²", "D²", "~", "C²", "."]**

and the output should be

**["G", "A......", "E²….~, "C²", "D²~", "C²."]**

All Dot(.), hellip(…) and tilde(~) should stick with the previous index of an array.

My current code for now is this. I don't know what to do next because I'm not familiar all the built in functions in javascript.

```
var newArr = ["G", "A", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "E²", "…", ".", "~", "C²", "D²", "~", "C²", "."];

for(var i=0; i<newArr.length; i++)
  {
    if(/[\&nbsp;\&hellip;\~\.\…\*\_\/]/g.test(newArr[i]))
    {
      // delete this index and transfer current value to previous index
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to create a new array. If it is a normal character you can use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add it to that array. If it is a special character you can modify the last element of the new array instead.

Comment: Will there ever be a special character at the first position in the array? And if so, what should happen?

Comment: Any edge cases, such as `[ 'A', '...B' ]`, `[ 'hello', `foo...bar`, 'world' ]`?

Comment: @DBS None, cause I only done the rest of the code to evade that kind of situation. Only single letter and superscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```js
var str = ["G", "A", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "E²", "…", ".", "~", "C²", "D²", "~", "C²", "."];

var newStr = str.join('').match(/([\w][^\w]*)/ig);
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Wow! Without even using loop. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if the input is `[ 'A', '...B' ]` ?

Comment: @Cid I don't think it will work if the case is different.

Comment: @enrique welcome :). It uses loops internally if I recall correctly. just FYI.

Comment: This is an equivalent of that regular expression: `/(\w\W*)/ig`

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array and add the wanted parts to the predecessor.

```js
const 
    data = ["G", "A", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "E²", "…", ".", "~", "C²", "D²", "~", "C²", "."],
    result = data.reduce((r, s) => {
        if (/^[\.²…~]$/.test(s)) r[r.length - 1] += s;
        else r.push(s);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

if i correctly understand what do you want , you can do it like that :) :

```js
    var newArr = ["G", "A", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "E²", "…", ".", "~", "C²", "D²", "~", "C²", "."];
    var detect = [".","~", "…"]
    var tab  = [];
    for(var i=0; i<newArr.length; i++)
    {
        var find = 0 ;
        for (var j = 0 ; j < detect.length ; j ++){
            if(newArr[i] == detect[j]){
                find++;
            }
        }
        if(find > 0){
            tab[tab.length - 1] =tab[tab.length - 1] + newArr[i];
        }else{

            tab.push(newArr[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(newArr);
    console.log(tab);
```

Comment: Thanks. Mr_Green already got the answer. But I upvoted your answer though cause the output is the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just `.join()` and `.split()` is sufficient.

```js
var ss = ["G", "A", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "E²", "…", ".", "~", "C²", "D²", "~", "C²", "."],
    rs = ss.join("").split(/(?=\w)/);

console.log(rs);
```

Comment: You can remove the match for any character from the regular expression, just splitting taking into account word characters should be enough. `/(?=\w)/`.